# How do I get bound variables in the Spring boot(or spring mvc, spring webmvc)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do I get http request parameter values, URL template values,  and  JSON request body value inside `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument()`?

Of course, I know how to get these values from `HttpServletRequest`. But, is there way to get these values from binding definitions? I think it will be easier to read source code than using `HttpServletRequest`.

Below is what I want to do. (see `<Something class for binder variable access>` )

```
public class FooResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return Foo.class.equals(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        String strfooId = <Something class for binder variable access>.getBinderVariableByFieldName("fooId");

        Long fooId = Long.parseLong(strFooId, 10);
        FooEntity fooEntity = fooRepository.findOne(fooId);
        FooDto fooDto = new FooDto();
        fooDto.setId(fooEntity.getId());
        fooDto.setName(fooEntity.getName());
        return fooDto;
    }

    private FooDto getFooDto(Long fooId) {
    }

}

@Controller
public class UsingFooController01 {

    /** fooDto is automatically set by HandlerMethodArgumentResolver */
    @RequestMapping("/xxx/yyy")
    public String controllerMethod(Model model, @RequestParam("fooId") String fooId, FooDto foodto) {
        model.addAttribute("foo", fooDto);
        return "sample_page";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your desired output more precisely? What do you mean with you want to access a relational database before your controller processes? Please also describe what do you have as "whole" (e.g. client-server architecture?)

Comment: "whole" means spring applicaton context (all of my code, and library)

Comment: @IvoVidovic Thank you for your reply. I added a little explanation.

Comment: You put the `@Controller` annotation on a function, but it is as far as I know exclusive to classes. Also, if UsingFooController01 should be a class, you need to put the annotations like in your 3 patterns inside the class, so when your REST service (I suppose) gets called, it is able to read out the parameters

Comment: I fixed 2 points., 1st is `public String UsingFooController01` to `public String UsingFooController01`. 2nd , I added  @RequestMapping annotation to controllerMethod.　I will return the topic, I want to get parameters and some other values BEFORE CONTROLLER! 
"some value" means  path variable, request param, and other binded value(json field, http header...).

Comment: I am a bit confused. Your Controller class will be the entry point for the client (application) if you are trying to implement a REST service (I am not sure if this is your goal). If you are saying you want the DB to do something based on parameters you receive before the Controller processes, how do you imagine that? The controller is used to 1. get the requests from the user/client application, 2. handle it (this could be the call of the DB functions) and return some answer to the client. If you want to omit step 1, where do the parameters come from?

Comment: Do you know ServletFilter(java) or before_action(rails)?
These features are work at before controller process.

ServletFilter and before_action is used for common processing for each controllers. For example, login check, csrf token check, ....

I have many controllers that are accessing a FooEntity(FooEntity's primary key is fooId). 
So I came up the idea of DB access before controller process, and pass  found entity to controller via HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.